# How to stop Grid, GridRow, GridItem from assigning proportional column widths

Tags: apache-flex, layout, flex4

In Flex4 we use Grid, GridRow and GridItem to layout the components of our screens. Most screens look OK, but quite a few appear with large amounts of space between the label and field. This mainly happens when we want to have something like the following scenario...

```
Name    [____________]
Age     [__]
Gender  [_]

Details
[__________________________________________]
[__________________________________________]
[__________________________________________]


|<col 1>|<------------ col 2 ------------->|
|<---------- grid and row width ---------->|
```

...where the Labels are in the first column, the top three fields are in the second column, and the bottom three fields span across both columns. Above is how we would like it appear, but Flex renders it like this...

```
Name            [____________]
Age             [__]
Gender          [_]

Details
[__________________________________________]
[__________________________________________]
[__________________________________________]


|<--- col 1 --->|<-------- col 2 --------->|
|<---------- grid and row width ---------->|
```

We don't have the ability to set individual column widths in each screen as a) there are thousands of screens and b) the labels and components can be internationalised.

I can't quite work out the algorithm they use to assign each column its width, but I think it looks for the widest component in each column and then uses these to assign each column an appropriate proportional width.

All we want is for each column to be as thin as possible so it just contains just its widest component (ignoring those that span of course), and doesn't have any extra whitespace. Does anyone know how to achieve this result?

Comment: Why don't you use `Form` and `FormItems`? They do this out of the box.

Comment: Thanks @RIAstar for the suggestion - a few reasons why we probably won't go down that path... a) existing code is too involved to rework and it works fine for our latest versions - I'm trying to render our old legacy system in the new rendering engine b) most of our screens are very complex (esp the legacy ones) - the above example was just for illustration purposes c) we need control of the layout row too (I'm not sure if you can do that in Forms?) as we allow customers to personalise the screen to suit their business flows (ie move fields/row/tabs, hide components, rename labels etc)